# How to reduce the file size of an image in access using vba

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, capacity

I have an access file and i want to find a way to reduce the file size of the images that i insert using VBA code.

More specifically they gave me an access application where you can insert an image by drag and drop. I want these images when they drop them in the application immediately reduce their file size. For example if the image is 195KB i want to reduce it to 35KB.

I am new in the vba coding and and in access and i search the web but nothing helps me.

Any ideas??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean "reduce the *size*" of the image? (the "capacity" is the maximum size you would store)

Comment: Do not use the term 'capacity'. It's called file size. What you're aiming to do is image compression. Here are two links: [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fab0ca75-f79d-4537-a1d4-c37f10371f66/excel-2007-compress-pictures-with-vba?forum=isvvba) and [here](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?16134-Solved-Macro-VBA-to-Compress-Picture). If you're new to VBA coding, you'll have to study some basic tutorials before you can do something as complicated as what you want.

Comment: you are right for the file size. Thanks a lot and sorry for the mistake